# WordPress: fresh install: Twenty Twelve theme does not display images

Tags: wordpress, installation, wordpress-theming, default

Here is how I installed WordPress. I installed xampp in C:\xampp
and started apache and mysql, created the wordpresstest database,
extracted wordpress-3.5.1.zip to C:\xamppp\htdocs\wordpresstest
and did an http:// localhost/wordpresstest and proceeded with
the installation (I did this twice because I wanted the
root directory to have a different name, so I deleted
the database and recreated it and deleted my
wordpress folders and reextracted them and
reinstalled).

The problem I am having is that the Twenty Tweleve theme is
not displaying any images:

[image]

whereas the Twenty Eleven theme (the only other theme that
came with wordpress) seems to be working fine:

[image]

Can someone please explain to me why the default install theme
(Twenty Twelve) is not working as expected? Basically it does
not seem to be able to use the right style information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spite of what appears in the theme screenshot, Twenty Twelve doesn't seem to have a default header image.

Go to Appearance -> Header and try to upload a header image.

Answer (score 2):

Twenty twele doesnt have a default header image.If you want add a image to header you can add it from Appearance. The two default themes have different themes. There is no any issue with  your installation or Wordpress. This is how it comes and you have to select any theme that is suitable for your preference and customize it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. And I didn't forget to click on Upload and then Save after clicking Browse... to browse for the desired image to include in the header.